# Split pandas string column into an array and match that array to another array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
       var1    var2
0    A_B_C_D    123
1    E_F_G_H    456
2    I_J_K_L    789
```

I want to query the data frame by splitting var1 on '_', then matching that to another array that I have defined. Lets say that array is `array_to_match_to =
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` then I would want to filter the data frame to get only row 0.

Also, I would like to match regardless of order, so matching to ['D', 'A', 'B','C'] also returns row 0.

Is there an easy and efficient way to do this other than iterating over all the rows of the df using `.iterrows`?

Comment: Would there be exactly one character string separating an underscore? Also, what must be the output if there is more than one match?

Comment: Let's say `df` is your dataframe. You can do something like this:

`df['var_1'] = df['var_1'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_'))`

`sample_df = df[df['var_1'] == arr_to_match_to]`

Comment: No, in practice I would like to do a regex split. If there are multiple matches, it just returns a df with everything but those matches removed.

Comment: @Nain yeah that was my first thought but it's pretty slow, so I was wondering if there was a way to do it with np-based functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings can be split with the `pd.Series.str` method `str.split`:

```
df['var1'] = df['var1'].str.split('_')
```

For the order-independent match, things are trickier, and if only trying to match one external list as in your example,  I might first shift focus, by using `str.join` on array_to_match_to and finding matching values, rather than splitting in the dataframe.

Then, to extend this to all orderings of array_to_match_to, the permutations can be taken explicitly, as below

```
from itertools import permutations
df[df['var1'].isin(['_'.join(m) for m in permutations(array_to_match_to)])]
```

Which matches on row zero for both `array_to_match_to = ['A', 'B','C', 'D']` and `array_to_match_to = ['D', 'A', 'B','C']`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.split`

```
match = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df[(np.array(df.var1.str.split('_').values.tolist()) == match).all(1)]

      var1  var2
0  A_B_C_D   123
```

Or with `np.core.defchararray.split`

```
match = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
splits = np.stack(np.core.defchararray.split(df.var1.values.astype(str), '_'))

df[(splits == match).all(1)]

      var1  var2
0  A_B_C_D   123
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df[(np.array(df.var1.str.split('_').values.tolist()) == match).all(1)]
%timeit df[(np.stack(np.core.defchararray.split(df.var1.values.astype(str), '_')) == match).all(1)]

1000 loops, best of 3: 399 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 266 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split var1, sort it and then compare it with the match list to get a mask array and then use it to select the rows.

```
df
Out[432]: 
      var1  var2
0  A_B_C_D   123
1  E_F_G_H   456
2  I_J_K_L   789
3  D_A_B_C   789

match= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']    
df[df.var1.str.split('_').apply(sorted).apply(lambda x np.array_equal(x,match))]

Out[430]: 
      var1  var2
0  A_B_C_D   123
3  D_A_B_C   789
```